# Adding arraylist to Jlist

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, serversocket

I have an arraylist in my metod receiveArrayLists which i want to add to a JList. How can i do this?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Scrollbar;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI implements Runnable {

private Server server;
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
private JList jl = new JList();
private JTextArea jl1 = new JTextArea();
private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(jl);
private Socket socket;
private DataInputStream dis;
private ObjectInputStream ois = null;
private DataOutputStream dos;

public GUI() {

    socket = new Socket();
    InetSocketAddress ipPort = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 4444);
    try {
        socket.connect(ipPort);
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    new Thread(this).start();


    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(50, 300, 420, 400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    pane.add(jl);
    pane.add(jl1);
    jl1.setEditable(false);
    jtf.setBounds(50, 40, 150, 40);
    jl.setBounds(50, 90, 150, 200);
    jl1.setBounds(210, 90, 150, 200);


    jtf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (dos != null) {
                if(jtf.getText().length() >0){
                try {
                    dos.writeUTF(jtf.getText());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                }else{
                    jl1.setText("");
                }
            }

        }
    });
    frame.add(jtf);
    frame.add(jl);
    frame.add(jl1);

    frame.add(pane);
}

public void run() {
    String fromServer;
    try {
        while ((fromServer = dis.readUTF()) != null) {
            if (fromServer.equals("read")) {
                receiveArrayList();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Here is my metod, as you can see, i try to use append which obviously wont work to add an arraylist to a JList

```
public void receiveArrayList() {

    try {
        jl1.setText("");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<String> a = (ArrayList<String>) (ois.readObject());
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            jl.append(a.get(i) + " \n");
        }
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI g = new GUI();

}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest is to create a DefaultListModel object, iterate through the ArrayList in a for or foreach loop and add the items to the model via its `addElement(...)` method. Then set the JList's model to your model.

More involved but satisfying is to create your own ListModel by extending AbstractListModel using your ArrayList as the model's nucleus.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee: That's interesting and is big news to me. So you're saying that Oracle will break much of the existing Swing code base? Can you please show a link to a valid reference on this?

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee the java 7 docs talk about it been backed by Vector and "in a future release it will be a real Collection implementation" which would suggest otherwise

Comment: +1 for using the model. Possible misunderstanding of "Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases."

Comment: Hm, where did @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee and his wild prediction go?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That comment is there in the Java6 docs as well. I think it's unlikely to be ever changed by Oracle with Swing in maintenance mode. For example that ListModel is now generic is an outside contribution.
In JavaFX views are backed by (observable) collections (replacing any data model classes completely).

Comment: @WalterLaan That might be where the original comment came from

Comment: @Mad: If he's going to say that, then why state that DefaultListModel is being kicked to the curb? Might as well state that Swing is being kicked on over (which it sort of is).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Given some of the questions I've read here, I would not be surprised if people thought JavaFX was Swing or Swing's replacement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make use the JList's [list model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html).  The simplest solution is to use [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), but you could investigate implementation your own (based on the [AbstractListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html))

If you don't want to keep any previous content when you receive the array list you could do the following:

```
public void receiveArrayList() {

    try {

        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        jl1.setText("");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<String> a = (ArrayList<String>) (ois.readObject());
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            model.addElement(a.get(i)); // <-- Add item to model
        }
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        jl.setModel(model); // <-- Set the model to make it visible

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the previous list, then you need to ensure that the original model is a `DefaultListModel` (in this example) or is compatible with the `ListModel` you are using.

Basically, then you want to cast the model:

You may want to check out this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more info.
    DefaultListModel model = jl.getModel();

Obviously, you won't need to reapply it at the end ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works just fine now. As you mentioned, your method is the correct way, because i dont want to keep previous content.